# Is it necessary to use critical points in this exercise?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have a question regarding the resolution of the following exercise:

Let be a quadratic form $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \langle A \cdot x, x \rangle$, where $A$ is a symmetric matrix. Show that if $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a critical point of restriction $f \vert_{S^{n-1}}$ then $Au = \lambda u$, where $\lambda = f(u)$.

**Comments:** I thought of the following solution:
Let $u \in S^{n-1}$. Then $f(u) = \langle Au, u \rangle$.
On the other hand, $f(u) = f(u)\langle u, u \rangle = \langle f(u)u, u\rangle$.

Thus, $Au = f(u)u$.

However, I did not use the hypothesis, but I find where the error is.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How did you deduce that $Au=f(u)u$?

Comment: Really, I have $\langle Au- f(u)u , u \rangle = 0$.  Why I conclude by using that $u$ is critical point?

Answer (score 1):

Since $u$ is a critical point of $f \vert_{S^{n-1}}$, it is also a critical point of $\frac{\langle Ax,x\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}$. Conversely, it is obvious that if $u$ is a critical point of $\frac{\langle Ax,x\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}$ (*unrestricted*) for $|u|=1$, then $u$ is also a critical point of $f \vert_{S^{n-1}}$. The task is easy. We find all critical points $u$ of $\frac{\langle Ax,x\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}$ with $|u|=1$.

Obviously, $\frac{\langle Ax,x\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}$ is smooth for $x\neq \underline{0}$. This implies that the critical points of $\frac{\langle Ax,x\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}$ are either $u=\underline0$ or those $u\neq\underline0$ for which $\nabla \frac{\langle Ax,x\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}\vert_{x=u}=0$. For the latter, we have
$$
\langle u,u\rangle Au=\langle Au,u\rangle u\overset{|u|=1}{\implies} Au=\langle Au,u\rangle u=f(u)u,
$$
which is as desired.